# mysql SELECT last value from 2 tables, 2 columns (with the same name)

Tags: mysql

Table '2_1_journal'

```
NumberRenamed
-------------
 1
 2
 3
```

Table '2_1_paidused'

```
NumberRenamed
-------------
 1
 2
```

Want to select last values from each table and get array with the 2 values.

Based on examples, created such code

```
SELECT 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed, 2_1_paidused.NumberRenamed 

FROM 2_1_journal

LEFT JOIN 2_1_paidused ON 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed = 2_1_paidused.NumberRenamed

ORDER BY NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1


$stmt->execute();
$ArrayWithTwoNumbers = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

But get error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'NumberRenamed' in order clause is ambiguous`.

If remove `ORDER BY NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1` get value `1` (first value from `2_1_journal.NumberRenamed`).

Please advice what need to correct.

Simple way would be 2 queries with `SELECT`. But from my knowledge to save resources better to use one query....

Changed to `ORDER BY 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1` and get `123`

Changed to

```
(SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_journal
UNION
SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_paidused)

ORDER BY NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1
```

get `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_paidused) ORDER BY NumberRenamed DESC LI' at line 2`

Changed to

```
(SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_journal )
UNION ALL
(SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_paidused)

ORDER BY NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1
```

no error, but result is not as expected (get last value from table 2_1_paidused). How to get last value also from table 2_1_journal?

**Seems this is solution**

```
(SELECT NumberRenamed as Number1 FROM 2_1_journal ORDER BY Number1 DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT NumberRenamed as Number2 FROM 2_1_paidused ORDER BY Number2 DESC LIMIT 1)
```

and `$stmt->fetchAll();`

Get

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Number1] => 3
        [0] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Number1] => 2
        [0] => 2
    )
```

Values are correct (as expected). But why in `[0]` and `[1]` there is `[Number1]`? Expected in `[1]` `[Number2]`

Comment: You can't sort by 2 different columns simultaneously. Maybe, using a UNION, and selecting 2 records, will help

Comment: use inner join nnot left join

Comment: with inner join got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test something like:

```
select
  (select max(NumberRenamed) from 2_1_journal) max1,
  (select max(NumberRenamed) from 2_1_paidused) max2
```

It is just a little better than 2 distinct queries, the only difference is it has 1 remote call (network overhead), but using 2 distinct queries results 2 remote calls.

Comment: As result get `123`. Possibly first 3 values from table `2_1_journal`

Comment: I had to use `fetchAll()`. Got `    [0] => Array
        (
            [max1] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [max2] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )`

Answer (score 0):

add either of the table name like `2_1_journal.NumberRenamed`

```
SELECT 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed, 2_1_paidused.NumberRenamed 

FROM 2_1_journal

LEFT JOIN 2_1_paidused ON 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed = 2_1_paidused.NumberRenamed

ORDER BY 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Get ` Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2_1_journal.NumberRenamed' in 'order clause'`

Comment: you said you get data when you applied column and. `and get 123`.. and now you are saying you are getting error?

Comment: Got unknown column error for this code `SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_journal
UNION
SELECT NumberRenamed FROM 2_1_paidused

ORDER BY 2_1_journal.NumberRenamed DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: With `fetchAll()` got `    [0] => Array
        (
            [NumberRenamed] => 
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 
        )`